# Best way to (git) clone app into Django project directory

Tags: django, git

I want to clone (via GIT) an external app into my project directory. Unfortunately there is one folder on top of the project that makes Django not see the cloned folder as an app.

For example see [allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth). After cloning the app itself is in `allauth/allauth` resp. from the project view `my_project/allauth/allauth`. If just adding `allauth` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, the app is not found by the server. I also tried adding `allauth.allauth`, which also doesn't work.

What is the recommended way to clone an external app into a Django project folder (and manage it as submodule for example)?

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to clone the app into your project? What about just installing `django-allauth` package via `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

you can clone it into a vendor/ directory and then symlink it's app folder into your project, but I'd recommend against that.

A better way would be to use a virtual environment, and install the application as an editable package.

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com.au/person/project@v0.1.1#egg=project
```

This will clone the repo into the src/ folder in your virualenv and set up the paths correctly such that it can be loaded normally with django.